# What is C++ version of realloc(), to allocate the new buffer and copy the contents from the old one?

Tags: c++, malloc

In C we used `malloc(), free()`, but in C++ youare using `new, delete`, but in C we also have `realloc`, which will alloc the new block and copy the old data (common minimum) and then free the old data bock. So what is the C++ version of that? I can write my own of course, but is there a builtin thing?

```
main() {
  int i; char *x = malloc(3);
  x[0] = 10;
  x[1] = 20;
  x[2] = 30;
  realloc(x, 4);
  x[3] = 40;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%i\n", x[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no equivalent of realloc in C++.

Comment: I'd use a std::vector for that

Comment: Does anyone know if any std::vector implementations use C memory handling for POD types?

Comment: @RossHemsley I know! It doesn't. I made a simple wrapper around the STL allocator that simply gets the normal functions from it called, but prints info about how they're called. And when a vector reallocates, it allocates new data, copies the elements, destroys the old elements, and lastly deallocates the old data. (If the realloc is caused by a push_back operation, the new element is constructed in the new data before old elements get copied over.) Do note that this is on Windows 10 with MSVC, behavior may differ elsewhere.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's no `new`/`delete` equivalent of `realloc` in C++.

From [Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#renew) :

> Why doesn't C++ have an equivalent to realloc()?
>
> If you want to, you can of course use realloc(). However, realloc() is
> only guaranteed to work on arrays allocated by malloc() (and similar
> functions) containing objects without user-defined copy constructors.
> Also, please remember that contrary to naive expectations, realloc()
> occasionally does copy its argument array. **In C++, a better way of
> dealing with reallocation is to use a standard library container, such
> as vector, and let it grow naturally**.

If you want a resizeable container, just use `std::vector`, otherwise stay with `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`.

And, to answer your last question, the closest C++ version of your code would be:

```
main() {
    std::vector<char> x(3);
    x[0] = 10;
    x[1] = 20;
    x[2] = 30;
    x.resize(4);
    x[3] = 40;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
}
```

But that is not the standard way of using a vector and provide little benefits versus simply:

```
main() {
    std::vector<char> x;
    x.push_back(10);
    x.push_back(20);
    x.push_back(30);
    x.push_back(40);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: With a container, how would you efficiently free memory by reducing the number of bytes needed? You can do this by providing `realloc` with a smaller number of bytes.

Comment: What if I want more control, like I want to control the growing policy?

@xuhdev, in the std::vector you can use 'shrink_to_fit()'. You would do this after you know for certain it will not grow anymore. The 'extra' memory will then be available for other purposes.

Comment: @QwertYuiop `shrink_to_fit` doesn't assure reducing memory used by the container. See [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit): "It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled."

Comment: @xuhdev, if your implementation doesn't fulfill that request, then in my opinion that is a shitty implementation. You can check with 'capacity()' before and after whether it actually works. I just tested on my system with GCC 12 and it works.

Comment: @QwertYuiop Actually the implementations don't always fulfill that request may be the smarter ones (if not the lazy ones) :) The reason it's non-binding is to allow C++ standard library implementations to optimize. See the "Remarks" in the proposal document: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue755

Answer (score 24):

Let's see what Bjarne Stroustrup thinks!

### [Why doesn't C++ have an equivalent to realloc()?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#renew)

> If you want to, you can of course use realloc(). However, realloc() is
>   only guaranteed to work on arrays allocated by malloc() (and similar
>   functions) containing objects without user-defined copy constructors.
>   Also, please remember that contrary to naive expectations, realloc()
>   occasionally does copy its argument array.
>
> In C++, a better way of dealing with reallocation is to use a standard
>   library container, such as vector, and let it grow naturally.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't have a `new/delete` equivalent of C's `realloc`.

The probable reason (although it is not mentioned anywhere in the Standard) is because of constructors that can throw: how should it behave if, while reallocating, a constructor throws? The handling of this case is best left to the programmer because there is not one true answer.

Comment: Honestly, if a constructor throws, that is the death of the program, sorry no redemption.

Answer (score 4):

`realloc` isn't used in C++ because C++ wants to use its copy and default constructors and destructors for things like this in general. But if you got plain old types that you want to handle as fast as possible, there is no reason not to roll your own array class that does what you want. I'm surprised there isn't one that's mostly STL-compatible already in the top Google page.