# Dynamic Array Using Strings in a Function Issues

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to run a dynamic array that employs strings, but when I push it through a function I get compile errors `'dynamicArray': undeclared identifier`, `'string':undeclared identifier`, and `illegal use of type 'void'`. All of these errors point to the header for some reason.

I call the pointer here:

```
string* dynamicArray = NULL;
```

I call the function here:

```
populateArray(dynamicArray);
```

What is in the header:

```
void populateArray(string *&dynamicArray);
```

The function:

```
void populateArray(string *&dynamicArray)
{
char decide;
bool moreStrings = true;
int counter = 0;
while (moreStrings == true)
{
    counter ++;
    dynamicArray = new string[counter];
    cout << "\nEnter your string here:";
    cin >> dynamicArray[counter - 1];
    cout << "\nDo you want to enter another string? Y/N:";
    cin >> decide;
    decide = toupper(decide);
    if (decide == 'N')
    {
        moreStrings = false;
    }
}
}
```

PS: vector may be better, but I'm afraid that isn't an option. Please only offer fixes that deal with pointers.

Comment: Where do you do "string* dynamicArray = NULL;" ? Are you sure it is not put mistakenly in a place out of a function scope?

Comment: string is from the std string library ? you should add header file #include <string> using namespace std, and It seems the new string array will cover the older one

Comment: Until the user enters 'N' you keep overwriting the dynamicArray pointer without deleting it prior to that.

Comment: My problems were caused by lacking using namespace std in the header file.

Comment: Note that `using namespace std` is not advisable. Just type `std::string` instead of `string` :)

Comment: That is just one of problems. There are more than two logic errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` added, it compiles just fine for me.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void populateArray(string *&dynamicArray);

int main(){
    string* dynamicArray = NULL;
    populateArray(dynamicArray);
    return 0;
}

void populateArray(string *&dynamicArray)
{
    char decide;
    bool moreStrings = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (moreStrings == true)
    {
        counter ++;
        dynamicArray = new string[counter];
        cout << "\nEnter your string here:";
        cin >> dynamicArray[counter - 1];
        cout << "\nDo you want to enter another string? Y/N:";
        cin >> decide;
        decide = toupper(decide);
        if (decide == 'N')
        {
            moreStrings = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `<string>` in your header file.

BTW, there might be potential memory leak in your code, if moreString is true, dynamicArray will point to another new string array, without deleting current one.

Comment: Also don't forget `using std::string`.

Comment: Yes, actually `using namespace std;` is enough.

Comment: But is not recommended, since you bring in the whole std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I see a bigger problem than the missing include and the using clause...

You wrote:

```
dynamicArray = new string[counter];
```

But this will allocate a new memory area for you every time. It does not copy the previously allocated elements. IF you don't want to use std::vector, you need to use malloc for the first element and than call realloc to copy your previously allocated data to your new one.

Check this form more info: [What is C++ version of realloc(), to allocate the new buffer and copy the contents from the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714937/what-is-c-version-of-realloc-to-allocate-the-new-buffer-and-copy-the-conten)