# How to expand allocated memory in place

Tags: c++, c, c++11, memory-management

Is there something like `std::realloc` but do nothing if it fails to expand the existing memory (of course it will let you know it failed)?

I mean truly expand in place. Not copy to a newly created memory chunk.

Comment: When std::vector<T> fills to current capacity, it automatically expands capacity (typically doubling it).    I'd say 'expanding' capacity is 'built in'.  So, even if there was something like realloc, why would you use it?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I can imagine a vector that tries to expand in place. Saves a lot of copies and some management. But then that only requires `std::realloc`.

Comment: What do you want to do that `std::realloc` doesn't achieve? Can you provide a use case? This sounds awfully like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PasserBy `std::realloc` might do a copy. It's a `C` function so it's not reliable to copy non-pod C++ type I think.

Comment: no.  there's no built in function in C that will do that.

Comment: No, nothing like that.

Comment: What is your plan for dealing with a failure return?

Comment: It's not just that there's no C function for it, dynamic memory allocation simply can't guarantee that another object hasn't been allocated right being the target to be grown.  You have to copy one of them in that situation.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is to use mmap to allocate and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html to reallocate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what other answers say, the function you need *could* be provided by the C standard ibrary. It isn't for some reason or other.

It was considered for an adition to the C standard, see e.g. http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1527.pdf (search for try_realloc). I don't know if the C committee is still pursuing this.

Bottom line, there's no such function as of now.

Answer (score 2):

*No*, there is no such function.

From your comments, I suppose that the following might be of interest to you: [`std::realloc` for non-POD types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905594/stdrealloc-for-non-pod-types) and [What is C++ version of realloc(), to allocate the new buffer and copy the contents from the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714937/what-is-c-version-of-realloc-to-allocate-the-new-buffer-and-copy-the-conten)

---

<sub>PS: Re-approach your problem, since the existing methology is most usually enough.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> truly expand in place. Not copy to a newly created memory chunk.

**This is impossible** because of how [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) works on direct-addressing (non-segmented) [instruction set architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) like [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) (or [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), MIPS, [RISCV](http://riscv.org/), etc....).

<sup>(so that strong limitation is mostly not from software, but from your hardware, in the previous century some segmented architectures like [iAPX432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432) or [Rekursiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekursiv) have been proposed, but failed)</sup>

Let's suppose you want to realloc a pointer zone of one megabytes to get four megabytes of more memory. But the virtual address space of [your process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) could contain some other data -for some *other* `malloc`-ed zone or something else like a [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), a [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), etc...- used two megabytes ahead. So you need to *move* your (growing) zone -by asking your OS for some fresh 4 megabyte zone- and copy from the previous one.

On Linux, look into [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (e.g. type `man 5 proc` in a terminal) and into [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Run the `cat /proc/self/maps` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` commands in some terminal to get a better intuition about virtual address space. Be aware that all memory management is done above such `mmap` and related (sometimes, old `sbrk`) [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). So your `malloc` or `operator new` is (sometimes) using them (most of the time, reusing previously `free`-d zone is preferable). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to explore the system calls done by *existing* programs.

BTW, on Linux, both your C standard library and your C++ standard library are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You could study their source code.

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand more how OSes work. Consider reading some book on [Computer Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) (or at least some [slides](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~byoung/cs429/slides6-isa1.pdf) on the simplified Y86 architecture). You've got some deep misunderstanding about how your computer works.

Comment: It is all very interesting but hardly relevant. The normal `realloc` *either* (1) reallocates the block without changing its address, grabbing and adjoining an unallocated chunk right after the block, *or* (2) moves the block to a new address if there happens to be not enough unallocated bytes right after the block. OP asks for a function that either does (1) or returns a null pointer and leaves the block alone. The C standard could very well provide this function, there is nothing theoretically impossible about it. Every implementation does (1) if it can.