# Is it safe to use the "realloc" after the "new" operator in C++?

Tags: c++, realloc

As far as I know, there is no exact alternative for the `realloc` of `C` in `C++` like the `new` for `malloc`. However, when I use the `realloc`  in `C++` to alter the memory allocated by the `new` operator, it works fine.

Is it safe to use those two (`new` and `realloc`) like I do in the codes below or it can lead to some problems?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int size = 5;
    int * arr = new int[size]{ 1,3,5,7,9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << *(arr + i) << (i < size - 1 ? ' ' : '\n');

    size++;
    arr = (int*)realloc(arr, size * sizeof(int));

    *(arr + size - 1) = 11;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << *(arr + i) << (i < size - 1 ? ' ' : '\n');

    delete[] arr;
    //free(arr);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, which operator should I use in such a case to free the memory:  `delete[]` of `free()`?

Comment: None, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: The runtime library just doesn't go out of its way to make this intentionally fail.  It is however flaming UB when the element type is a C++ object, like std::string.  Internal pointers won't get updated.

Comment: @HansPassant Why on earth would anyone do this with a `std::string`?  Or indeed any kind of library object?  Everything to lose, nothing to gain (unless perhaps you thoroughly misunderstand `std::vector` or `std::array`).

Comment: And, interestingly, because `new` and `malloc` allocated from different heaps, "Edit n Continue" didn't work in VS2015, I think it was, because - as I discovered after a fair bit of digging - something was allocated with `malloc` and later freed with `delete`.  I patched `mspdsrv` and sailed on my merry way (it got fixed later).  Ironically, the bug was 'swallowed' by some invalid parameter handling logic so the developer who made this boo-boo never saw any evidence of it (other than the fact that his code didn't actually work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the behaviour is *undefined*. You can only call `delete[]` on a pointer that you've obtained from a call to `new[]`.

Using `std::vector` would cause all these memory issues to fall away.

Comment: [documentation of realloc says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc): Reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with a call to free or realloc. Otherwise, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe. `new` should only be matched by `delete` or `delete[]` - using it with `realloc` is dangerous and could lead to security risks.

Also, why are you using `new` and `delete` in the first place? Use containers like `std::vector` or smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` if you really want to manage memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix c memory functions with c++ memory functions or you're gonna have a bad time.

See this:
[What is C++ version of realloc(), to allocate the new buffer and copy the contents from the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714937/what-is-c-version-of-realloc-to-allocate-the-new-buffer-and-copy-the-conten/16714982)

Comment: As is this answer should be a comment